# Making a Remote Control for My TV from Scratch

Tags: infrared, transmitter, receiver, tv, remote

This might seem silly to many of you, but I lost my TV remote when I moved awhile back and instead of buying a universal remote for cheap, I want to make a remote for my TV from scratch myself. I'm talking about designing the pcb, soldering parts together, the whole shebang. I know nothing about electronics and thought it would be a great way to learn.

I just need some guidance on how to start or advice on whether this is even possible without having the original remote to decode the IR signals? Am I able to look up the IR codes for the receiver by looking up the model number of the TV? What components do I need and how do I organize them on the circuit board?

I know basic parts that I would need are an IR LED, transistors, push buttons, and a microcontroller. I'm not sure which specific transistors or microcontroller to use though or how to design the parts on the pcb. Pointing me in the direction of useful resources would definitely help. I've already read a few instructables and watched a few videos on making a remote, but none of them told me how to design one from scratch for a specific receiver without the original remote. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you have to ask if it's possible, it's probably not possible by you with your current knowledge and skills.

Comment: @TomServo Thanks for your response. That part was a typo. I meant to ask whether it was possible without the original remote to decode the IR signals. Thanks

Comment: The basic electronics are "easy enough". An IR LED, a driver transistor and a microcontroller. An Arduino (under $US5 for an Asian version) would be fine. The problem is getting the correct code sequences (as others have noted). "Easiest" would be to borrow a universal remote and create a learning remote that acquired the codes. | A hard approach is to write code ("easy enough") that sequences through all codes and leave it by the TV - when the TV changes channel / volume/ turns on/off / emits smoke. Stop the remote, go back NM seconds and step forward slowly.  ...

Comment: ... You'd learn a lot about Arduino programming - and find that the above would actually be doable as your learned even with no programming experience. BUT I do not recommend it. Finding all or even a few codes could take a long long time.

Comment: Quite a few of these link to relevant pages - Google image search [diy remote control ir arduino](https://www.google.com/search?q=diy+remote+control+ir+arduino&rlz=1C1CHBF_enNZ834NZ839&sxsrf=ACYBGNTqzVnF3CeuBEyGwOXYR_pJguXU-A:1580024354207&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiIwfmy4aDnAhVwzDgGHeceBkcQ_AUoAXoECCwQAw&biw=2048&bih=1057)

Comment: [A simple Arduino based learning remote control](https://www.electronicshub.org/diy-universal-remote-using-arduino/)

Comment: Just to say: If it's an RCA tv...you have a better chance winning the lottery than getting a universal remote that works, even less the codes for it. xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Creating a remote control with an IR led and a IC for registering/sending codes is actually pretty easy using a PIC micro-controller or the likes. And programs like PicBasic are very easy to learn and use for programming.

<strike>The issue lies with a very important problem:</strike>

**You need an actual remote that works with the TV to get the codes.**

There is absolutely no source online for IR codes. You need a functional remote for this, which makes it useless creating a new remote from scratch in the first place....

I guess I'm getting old or don't research often enough but if you really want to make a remote there is a few options:

You can make an arduino remote control. This uses very low cost parts and a bit of learning:
https://importgeek.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/send-tv-remote-signal-using-arduino/

A more compact way of doing this is using a PIC micro-controller. (ex. [PIC12F675](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/41190c.pdf) from Microchip) There is very little parts needed and has a smaller footprint. Programming is a bit harder, but m[any programs are already done for you](https://www.picbasic.nl/frameload_uk.htm?https://www.picbasic.nl/rc5_remote_uk.htm). Only editing the HEX codes is needed for the most part.

As for the HEX codes needed for the TV to recognize, they can be found here:

[remotecentral.com/cgi-bin/codes](http://www.remotecentral.com/cgi-bin/codes/) – Thanks to **Mattman944** for pointing that out!

If you have a Samsung tablet, some have IR transmitters. If so, you can use this as an alternative remote using remote control apps. Or simply buy a new remote off ebay/amazon.

Comment: The manufactures normally don't publish the codes, but people have reversed engineered them. http://www.remotecentral.com/cgi-bin/codes/

Comment: Guess I've been proven wrong. Thanks for the shoutout @Mattman944